# Is it possible to identify users without any authentication system?

Tags: php, html, web, ip

I'm wondering if it is possible to identify a user on my website without asking him to create an account ?
I know it is possible to use IP address, but IP often change if I'm not wrong ?
So, is there a method such as IP address to identify a user on long term ?

Comment: No, IP addresses are much too coarse for identifying individual computers, much less individual *people*. Use the same approach as a login would: *set a cookie.*

Answer (score 0):

You could set sessions that don't expire.

Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: This solution sounds great and simple, but an experimented user could stop the session, no ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the proper way to do it would be to store an unique token into the user's navigator using a cookie. 
But you won't be able to track him through different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that similar problem on my website by

1 - Figuring out ID from user's browsers by Valve/fingerprintjs method from [Github](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs)
This fingerprint can give unique number according to their browser. And it is 90+% about to be unique.
2 - Get user public information(if you want) by using this [api](http://pro.ip-api.com) ([demo](http://ip-api.com) )
That api will give you about user's public information. city,ip,timezone,country,network,lat:long of ISP, etc.

3 - Combining with generated token sessions and cookies for the best results .

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, yes I am updating.